# Python: how do i find the next business day for different countries

Tags: python, time

In python, I have a a set of dates for different countries. How do i find their next business date if the date given is a holiday for that country, given that different countries have different holiday calendars.

[image]

For example, if date is 23th Jan, 2023.Next business day for Hong Kong is 26th Jan 2023. For India, 23th Jan 2023 is not a public holiday, so it will return 23th Jan, 2023. For Singapore, next business date would be 25th Jan, 2023.

Comment: You need a database for it. Use some API like this https://dev.timeanddate.com/holidays/pricing. There should be free versions too.

Comment: Maybe use the [holidays package](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) to get the relevant holidays that you should skip?